# Some regex examples for Snort or ClamAV and there inputs

Tags: regex, antivirus, dfa, snort

I have the basic knowledge of regex. But I almost know nothing about the popular software Snort or ClamAV.

I am doing some projects which require some large real regex and their inputs. I found Snort and ClamAV -like software uses regex a lot. So I am curious about them.

Could you show some typical regex used in these softwares, and also their inputs?

Comment: http://blog.joelesler.net/2010/02/writing-snort-rules-correctly.html It seems that the flavor for Snort is PCRE, which you can find plenty of resources about.

Comment: For ClamAV, it seems that it supports POSIX regex (check Wikipedia or man page for POSIX regex). Not sure whether it is BRE or ERE, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh  thanks! I downloaded the rules from snort.org, which contain many "pcre".

Answer (score 0):

ClamAV doesn't use regular expressions.  It has *some OR and AND* capability, but there's no current "regex" functionality in ClamAV